# View scheduled recordings remotely

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

I have one computer which is equipped with a TV tuner card. The Recorded TV folder is shared so that other computers on the network can watch recordings. Now that I am upgrading my computers to Windows 7, they have Media Center, which makes for a nicer viewing experience than a Windows Explorer folder view. I have set up Media Center on my laptop to considering the Recorded TV folder on the tuner-equipped PC as an extended library location, so now I can view all the recordings from within Media Center on the laptop.

To make this experience even better, is there a way to view the list of scheduled recordings on the tuner-equipped PC from within Media Center on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

[Remote Potato](http://ww2.fatattitude.com/software/software-item.aspx?appid=12) is really good for this. It's a free web server that runs on your media center and allows you remote access over the internet (or local network). You can browse the tv guide and schedule recordings remotely and even stream video to your browser (if you have silverlight installed and a fast enough connection).