# Is there a way to remotely schedule recordings with Media Center 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

Is there a way to remotely **schedule** recordings with Media Center on Windows 7?   I've tried using remote desktop, but find that media center quits as I connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a little more research has revealed a some options.

As @uSlackr suggested VNC is a workable option (+1), although possibly a little heavy handed when windows already has RDP.

Remote Potato also seems to address this issue and more (also pretty heavy handed). Some info on remote potato:

http://lifehacker.com/353559/watch-and-schedule-media-center-recordings-from-any-computer
[Windows Media Center command line options?](https://superuser.com/questions/225104/windows-media-center-command-line-options)
[View scheduled recordings remotely](https://superuser.com/questions/69736/view-scheduled-recordings-remotely)

Answer (score 2):

You could install VNC as a remote desktop tool.  It will reuse the console session and may not kill the Media Center
http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html